# Powerpoint 2013

Tags: sync, microsoft-powerpoint, animation

I want to animate a bike going across the screen, but I also want the spokes to spin. I have treated it as three separate pieces of art: bike + 2 wheels - but I can't get the wheels to travel across the screen at the same rate as the bike.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right, but probably you are in trouble at the animation part.

- For the 2 wheels set first the swirl animation (emphasis animations group)
- Then for the same 2 wheels go to "Add animation" button (this will add a second animation for the same object) and give it a motion path animation
- Set a motion path animation for the bike's frame as well
- Now go to "Animation Pane" and change the start option for all the animations to `Start with previous`

Done!

Here is a little preview of what I made (raw bike sketch :p - forgot to make the animation continuous, just refresh if you missed it)

[image]